# Cannot access AppDelegate variables

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've declared a variable in my app delegate:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) PFGeoPoint *shovelLocation;
```

I've synthesized it in my AppDelegate:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize shovelLocation;
```

I've imported the AppDelegate.h file into my other viewcontroller file which im trying to access this object from:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

The problem is that when i create the appDelegate object and try to access its properties, it says it doesn't have a shovelLocation property:

```
//get location
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
PFGeoPoint *location = appDelegate.shovelLocation;
                                   ^
                                      Property 'shovelLocation' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
```

Is this not a true instance of AppDelegate that I'm creating or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you try a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes I did that and i even restarted xcode as well

Comment: have u included the app delegate's header

Comment: as in #import "AppDelegate.h"?

Comment: Is #import <Parse/Parse.h> included somewhere? I assume it is, but that's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will resolve your problem but try retain instead of strong

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) PFGeoPoint *shovelLocation;
```

Also there is no need for a cast. (AppDelegate*)

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Answer (score 0):

write following code in `Appdelegate.h` file :

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) PFGeoPoint *shovelLocation;
+(AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate;
```

and write method in `Appdelegate.m`

```
+(AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

and write code following code for call this variable :

```
AppDelegate *app=[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];
PFGeoPoint *location = app.shovelLocation;
```

it is working , use it !